How to get the Account Object after AccountCreateOptions
I have this code which succeeds:
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "xxxx";
    var options = new AccountCreateOptions
    {
        Country = data.country,
        Email = data.businessEmail,
        BusinessType = "individual",
        Capabilities = new AccountCapabilitiesOptions()
        {
            CardPayments = new AccountCapabilitiesCardPaymentsOptions(){ Requested = true },
            Transfers = new AccountCapabilitiesTransfersOptions { Requested = true },
        },
        Controller = new AccountControllerOptions
        {
            Fees = new AccountControllerFeesOptions { Payer = "account" },
            Losses = new AccountControllerLossesOptions { Payments = "stripe" },
            StripeDashboard = new AccountControllerStripeDashboardOptions
            {
                Type = "full",
            },
            RequirementCollection = "stripe"
        },
    };
    var service = new AccountService();
    service.Create(options);

The stripe api says I should receive a response object like this:
{
"id": "acct_1Nv0FGQ9RKHgCVdK",
"object": "account",
"business_profile": {
"annual_revenue": null,
"estimated_worker_count": null,
"mcc": null,
"name": null,
"product_description": null,
"support_address": null,
"support_email": null,
"support_phone": null,
......

I'm looking in the AccountService Object:
var service = new AccountService();

But I cant seem to get back the response object with the id of example, so that i can get the url to start the onboarding process:
acct_1Nv0FGQ9RKHgCVdK

How do I do this in Stripe.net?
I get this info from the AccountService:


I had to use service.CreateAsync()
var responseObject = await service.CreateAsync(options);


The Account response is not returned to the service.  You need to create a new var and assign the value from service.Create(options) to it.  Essentially just like this
var account = service.Create(options)

That should return the full Account object to your code.  I recommend adding a line like
Console.WriteLine(account.id)

to confirm you have the data you expect.
